# jQuery plugins - the tab widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am studying a javascript - more precisely javaqueryui.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> 17. Installing and utilizing jQuery plugins</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.2.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="j17.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/dot-

luv/jquery-ui.css" />


</head>

<body>

<h1 id="title"> 17. Installing and utilizing jQuery plugins </h1>



<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. </p>
    <p>Duis cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me understand why, instead of seeing three tabs with 3 different contents, I see the 3 tabs with the same content?

Current result (visible regardless of which tab I switch to):

> Proin elit arcu.
>
> Morbi tincidunt.
>
> Mauris eleifend est et turpis.
>
> Duis cursus.

Expected/desired result:
Tab1 should show

> Proin elit arcu.

Tab2 should show:

> Morbi tincidunt.

Tab 3 should show:

> Mauris eleifend est et turpis.
>
> Duis cursus.

PS: In case you need to view the javascript file content:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

all other external script files are referenced from the internet, not downloaded locally (as the src attribute shows)

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your libraries, probably.

I tried your code on jsFiddle and it didn't work. Then I tried to include external libraries from [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples) example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Your HTML and JS code started work with that links ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r45xc/15/)) => libraries links were wrong or they conflicted.

So... Try another source... Check [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples) example on official jQuery UI site.